# Passport Google OAuth2 Need to logout before logging in

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to use passport to authenticate a google login, however, if you try to login the first time you enter the page, you get a TokenError:

```
TokenError: Bad Request
   at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
   at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
   at passBackControl (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
   at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
   at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
   at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
```

However, if you go to the logout endpoint, and then login, it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/login', authenticationController.handler);
app.post('/login', authenticationController.postLogin);
app.get('/logout', authenticationController.logout);

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope:['email', 'profile']}));
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/login'}), (req, res)=>{
    var returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
    req.session.returnTo = null;
    res.redirect(returnTo || '/');
});
```

and my passport configuration:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var users = {};
exports.OAuth2Strategy = new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:'ID',
    clientSecret:'secret',
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)=>{
    users[profile.id] = profile;
    done(null, profile);
});
passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
    done(null, users[id]);
});
exports.users = users;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've just been going in circles with this.